# DialogDisplayer text copyable

Tags: java, swing, dialog, messagebox

Is it possible to be able to copy/paste the text of an message box into email or for a URL. At the minute the text which is put up by DialogDisplayer.notify() is not selectable.

```
final NotifyDescriptor nd = new NotifyDescriptor.Message("Generated report is on server at: " +  reportUri);
                            nd.setTitle("Generated report");
                            DialogDisplayer.getDefault().notify(nd);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the version 7.0 of Netbeans. Here is the bug page: http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=187179

Comment: So what would be best plan B work around? was thinking something like new button to copy to clipboard maybe?

Comment: that would probably work. Or you could just write out the text to a different place.